# Why do MySQL AI id's behave this way?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a simple 3 column table.

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (

id INT,
name VARCHAR(40),
age INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

If I then insert lets say 5 values into the table there will be 5 records. Each record will have an `id` ranging from 1 - 5. If I were to delete 4 of the records, leaving me with the one that has the `id` of 1 and THEN insert another 4 records again, how come it doesn't start from  `id=2` but instead carries on so it'd start from 6?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes I do, hence the title `MySQL AI`.

Comment: Primary key doesnt go back,its value is in AUTO INCREMENT,the gaps are irrelevant.If you want reset use `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 2`

Comment: I assume it's just because it's easier and it doesn't introduce any unwanted behaviour or difference in resources needed. Checking for the largest ID is way easier than checking for gaps.

Comment: Because the value of a primary key has no meaning whatsoever. It is only a value to uniquely identify a row in the table. It does not matter whether the ID 42, 1, 3456 or 282091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a scenario that explains why it can't decrement the AI on DELETE:

1. Ashley starts a transaction and DELETEs rows for `id=2` through `id=5`. But Ashley doesn't commit immediately.
2. Bill starts his own transaction and INSERTs a new row. Since the `id` values 2 through 5 have been deleted, they'd up for grabs. Bill's row gets `id=2`.
3. Ashley rolls back the first transaction. Thus the rows for `id=2` through `id=5` come back.
   But Bill's transaction already inserted a new row with `id=2`!

An alternative would be to increment based on what each transaction can see, and ignore uncommitted changes:

1. Ashley DELETEs rows for `id=2` through `id=5`. Do not commit yet.
2. Bill starts his own transaction and INSERTs a new row. Since the `id` values 2 through 5 still appear to exist in Bill's view of the data, don't use those. Assign `id=6`.
3. Ashley commits the first transaction. Thus the rows for `id=2` through `id=5` are gone, and Bill's row has value `id=6`, resulting in a mysterious gap!

The only other way to avoid this would be to make all transactions serialized. In other words, Bill's INSERT would have to wait until Ashley's transaction resolved. It's desirable to avoid this, and allow concurrent inserts.

For this reason, AI mechanisms *must* function outside of transaction scope. Concurrent transactions can "see" the latest AI value for a table, even if there are uncommitted transactions in progress. And the only way to prevent re-using values is to always increment, and never decrement.

This does result in "gaps" from time to time. This is normal and expected. AI keys don't need to be consecutive, they only need to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because it's the easiest thing to implement. It can be implemented by having a single "next value" counter and incrementing it every time a new row is inserted.

Automatically resetting the next value would be extremely expensive. Since rows can be deleted in any order, the server would have to look through the entire table on every insert or delete to determine the next value.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually good for you; imagine you store these ids somewhere else; you can still identify the removed ones and keep track of the records you have and the ones you don't anymore.

Anyway, you can always set your primary key to INT or CHAR and then make a function to create your own ids.

Comment: This is a useful side effect, but not the actual reason for the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Each table has its own `AUTO_INCREMENT` counter that is consulted when a new ID needs to be auto-generated.  That value does not necessarily correspond to the current contents of the table, for a couple of reasons:

- Two simultaneous `INSERT` queries shouldn't auto-generate the same ID.  Were the max based on the actual contents of the table, both queries would see the same value of `MAX(id) + 1` -- particularly if both inserts are done in transactions -- and one of the queries would end up failing due to a duplicate key.
- MySQL lets you *set* the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, which defines the next value to be auto-generated.  That wouldn't be too much use if the DBMS just reset the value to `MAX(id) + 1` whenever it pleased.